# ESP32 output pin - internal pull-up/pull-down resistor

Tags: esp32

When configuring a pin as output on the ESP32, does it set an internal pull-up or pull-down resistor?

I am connecting a bus buffer  to an output pin, and I am not sure whether I should use a pull-up or pull-down resistor on the bus.

EDIT - Schematic:
[image: ESP32 with bus buffer]

Comment: How are you connecting the bus buffer? Can you draw a schematic?

Comment: just added the schematic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output pins output a certain voltage. Adding internal pull-up or pull-down resistors to output pins is silly because they won't do anything except for wasting power.

The output pin is equivalent to a 0-ohm pull-up or pull-down resistor already (depending on whether your software makes it high or low).

Comment: is it correct to say that only input pins require pullup/pulldown resistor to avoid floating potential if nothing is driving it?

Comment: @F.Heisenberg Yes. And output pins are *always* driven - by themselves.

Comment: What if the ouput pin is open drain?

Comment: @F.Heisenberg Well then it's floating instead of high, so you want a pull-up resistor to make it high. Most microcontroller outputs aren't open drain.

Comment: Okay, i think i2c ouputs are open drain

Comment: I2C outputs are open-drain, but internal pull-ups are too weak to use with I2C pins, they are in the order of tens of kilo-ohms. I am not saying that it does not work, it will just be extremely slow if it works, and not within rise time specs.

Comment: The output pin is not equivalent to a zero ohm (hyperbole aside) pull up or pull down when that output is tri-stated.

Comment: @SteveSh Then it's not an output pin. We call that an input pin.

Comment: @Justme: Yes for I2C pullup resistor need to be calculated based on line resistance and capacitance. But how do I know if an output pin is push/pull or open drain?

Comment: @F.Heisenberg you read the documentation or measure it. What are you going to use the pin for?

Comment: @Justme I understand. I am using 4 pins for an LED driver that has an interface similar to SPI.

Answer (score 2):

An output pin that is a push-pull output is a strong output - using an internal pull resistor (down or up) makes no sense.

Edit (due to new information): Since the ESP32 pin may not be an output when it boots up, it can be a floating input so the buffer output state is not known. Obviously to keep buffer output state stable and known during ESP32 boot, you need a pull-down (or pull-up) at the buffer input.

Comment: True.  But, if you're concerned that the bus might float if nothing is driving it (in the case of a shared bus) then it is considered good design practice to put weak pullups or pulldowns on the bus.  You could use the pullups/pulldowns on the buffer, if they are provided by the device manufacturer, to do this, rather than adding a bunch of discrete resistors.

Comment: I thought so too. But should I add a pull-up or pull-down resistor? Can I add both?

Comment: @Justme: can you provide a equivalent circuit of the output? Why is there no internal pull-up for example?

Comment: @SteveSh in that case, it's not an output pin!

Comment: @F.Heisenberg An output pin has a 0 ohm pull-up or pull-down resistor, depending on whether you set it high or low.

Comment: Okay i understand now, thank you. How can I find out if buffer has internal pullup/pulldown? It's not in the data sheet nor have a seen a schematic with buffers where pullups/pulldowns are used on the inputs.

Comment: Anyone know an answer to my previous question about pullup/pulldown for buffer?

Comment: Buffers don't have internal anything (some special models may have bus hold, but not your standard LVC125). You will only need a pull-up or pull-down if the ESP32 is disconnected from LVC125 for some reason, but that can be a special case that you can live with. If the ESP32 pin for some reason is not an output, like during boot, then external pull resistor might be a good idea. But pull-up or pull-down, we don't know what you would like for the idle state.

Comment: In my design I reserved space for a pullup and pulldown resistor. I would prefer to pull the input low during ESP32 boot. However, since ground the \OE pin, the output of buffer is anyways undefined during boot up so the question is how much sense the pulldown makes.

Comment: Since the buffer is always enabled, pull-down or pull-up at buffer input does make sense if you need the buffer output to be stable low or high during ESP32 bootup when the pin is not yet an output. Usually it is a good thing not to leave inputs floating in undefined state.